# nodejs print console.log to http

Tags: node.js, http, console.log

I made a script in NodeJS with multiple conditions.
I want to export/print the console.log to a webpage using NodeJS Server.

```
function myfunction() {
    app('Some text', 'ALERT!', function(err, remaining) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Some text.');
```

Is this possible? I've searched everywhere.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to print logs from server to a webpage in client side?

Comment: Because I want to use them in PRTG (monitoring tool)

Comment: Try using sockets for these kind of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to export/print the `console.log(...)` result to web page, you can override `console.log` and make it emit message before it is printed in server console. Then the message will be emitted to browser using Web Socket and printed/used in page.

Example code is listed below.

Server side:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

eventEmitter.on('logging', function(message) {
  io.emit('log_message', message);
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});

// Override console.log
var originConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = function(data) {
  eventEmitter.emit('logging', data);
  originConsoleLog(data);
};

// code for test.
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('X: ' + Math.random());
}, 2000);
```

Browser side:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('log_message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! When I use the script I will get the following error: (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 logging listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Comment: @user3130478 This is because a new `logging` event listener is added each time when there is an io connection. I've edited the code in answer and leave only one `logging` event listener. Please note this will make `console.log(...)` statement broadcast message to all client browsers.